# Ударения в словосочетаниях "без толку" и " не без толку"

Tags: орфоэпия

Б'ез толку, здесь понятно. А где падает ударение в словосочетании "не без толку"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Грамота.ру  предлагает два варианта для ***без толку***, в словаре Резниченко также указаны оба варианта

```
Вопрос № 259108
```

Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Правильно: **бЕз толку и без тОлку.**

https://russkiiyazyk.ru/question/postanovka-udareniya

*Вот попрекать мне станут, что **бЕз толку** всегда журю. Не плачь, я дело говорю.* (А. С. Грибоедов)

*Отрядом книг уставил полку, Читал, читал, а всё **без тОлку*** (А. С. Пушкин).

***БЕз толку*** — это *напрасно, зря*, а ***без тОлку*** — это про отсутствие тОлка.

Можно предположить, что ***не без тОлку*** сохраняет ударение  на существительном (*не без тОлку* — это *с тОлком*).

Нашлись единомышленники:  https://russkiiyazyk.ru/question/postanovka-udareniya

Answer (score 1):

> Б'ез толку, здесь понятно.

Не так уж все и понятно. Лопатин дает два варианта - б**е**з толку и без т**о**лку. К сожалению, в других словарях ничего посмотреть нельзя, там обычно не приводят "слова" (сочетания) с раздельным написанием.

Но если принять версию Лопатина, то и для конструкции с отрицательной частицей должно быть два варианта.
"Не б**е**з толку" и "не без т**о**лку". Вариант с ударением на частицу "не" можно исключить как фантастический.